# Recommendation for c#/visual studio unittesting tutorial?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

There are lots of tutorials on the net for unit testing c# programs with nunit, but can anyone recommend a good tutorial for using the built in visual studio tools to do unit testing that can be handed out to a newbie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379625%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Use the same tutorials.

The difference in syntax is minor, especially for the kinds of syntax used in tutorials.

You can see the differences [here](http://xunit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Comparisons&referringTitle=WhyDidWeBuildXunit).